# How to simplify the conditions in template to avoid multiple repetitions

Tags: reactjs, react-templates

I have a scenario like showing text as well adding class togathered. it look like i require to add multiple times with same elements nearly. what would be the correct approach for this kind of scenarios?

here is my template:

```
<span><a className={this.state.showMore ? 'active' : ''} onClick={this.showMore}>{this.state.showMore ? 'read less' : 'read more'}</a></span>
```

i have added the `state showMore` both `a` tag and the `text` inside. is there any simple way to handle same conditions across page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd create a component to handle read-more, and pass the props from where it's used if there's any, So same functionality is same across my application and if there's any improvements I can handle by it in one single place.

here is a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rbxbsc)

EX: functional component

```
export const ReadMore = ({ text, truncateLength = 10 }) => {
  const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState(false);

  const getText = () => {
    if (showMore) {
      return text;
    }

    const truncatedText = text.substring(0, truncateLength);
    if (text.length > truncateLength) {
      return `${truncatedText}...`;
    }

    return truncatedText;
  };

  return (
    <span>
      {getText()} &nbsp;
      <a
        className={showMore ? "active" : ""}
        onClick={() => setShowMore(!showMore)}
      >
        {text.length > truncateLength && (showMore ? "read less" : "read more")}
      </a>
    </span>
  );
};
```

and use it like this props could be:

- **text**: is the text that should be read-less or more.
- **truncateLength**: is the length that should show if the text length is
  greater, and optional prop, if this isn't provided `ReadMore`
  component will set the value to 10 by default, (check the props of
  `ReadMore`)

```
<ReadMore
    text="this is the text that should do the react-more and read-less"
    truncateLength={10}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{this.state.showmore ? 
<span><a className={'active'} onClick={this.showMore}>read less</a></span> 
:
<span><a onClick={this.showMore}>read more</a></span>
}
```

should be a more readable and clearer way of doing this. Basically when you have >1 thing depending on the same condition, take the condition outside would be my way to go!